# how to Pass touch event to button beneath view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have buttons and they work fine with touch event now i added view to show swype finger animation as shown in figure.

Now my buttons touch event is not working. Does anyone have any idea how to delegate touch and motion event from view to button beneath it thanks.

This is image of my problem

[image]